# App Crashes on Some Devices | Memory Issue?

Tags: android

So I recently finished initial development of my app. I'd been using my phone(OnePlus 2) the entire time for debugging and things were generally fine.
I decided to take some help from friends and family for testing the app and some have reported that the app crashes on startup. So I got hold of my mom's phone (Galaxy S5) and decided to logcat the error on that.

Logcat

```
04-16 10:23:02.400 3229-3229/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.test.drawernav time:3576923
04-16 10:23:02.730 3229-3229/? V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
04-16 10:23:02.835 3229-3229/? V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable/bg.jpg
04-16 10:23:02.885 3229-3229/? I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1308(219KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(80KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 118MB/126MB, paused 381us total 23.063ms
04-16 10:23:02.895 3229-3229/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 134MB to 128MB
04-16 10:23:02.895 3229-3229/? I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 481(22KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 118MB/128MB, paused 346us total 9.467ms
04-16 10:23:02.915 3229-3229/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 134MB to 128MB
04-16 10:23:02.915 3229-3229/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 58(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 118MB/128MB, paused 392us total 18.452ms
04-16 10:23:02.915 3229-3229/? I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 43MB allocation
04-16 10:23:02.935 3229-3229/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 134MB to 128MB
04-16 10:23:02.935 3229-3229/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 118MB/128MB, paused 521us total 17.392ms
04-16 10:23:02.980 3229-3229/? E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 45619212 byte allocation with 9890668 free bytes and 9MB until OOM"
04-16 10:23:02.980 3229-3229/? D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
04-16 10:23:02.985 3229-3229/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-16 10:23:03.010 3229-3229/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.test.drawernav, PID: 3229
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.drawernav/com.test.drawernav.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                     at com.test.drawernav.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                     at com.test.drawernav.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 45619212 byte allocation with 9890668 free bytes and 9MB until OOM
                                                     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:741)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:562)
                                                     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3723)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3596)
                                                     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:750)
                                                     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3939)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:511)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:507)
                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:351)
                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:347)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                     at com.test.drawernav.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The main activity is called after a Splash Screen (which runs on every phone) is displayed for 5 seconds. The main activity houses a navigation drawer around which the entire application has been designed.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView navList;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigationdrawer);
        ArrayList<String> navArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        navArray.add("Home");
        navArray.add("About Us");
        navArray.add("Our Work");
        navArray.add("Locate Us");
        navArray.add("Contact Us");


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                navArray);
        navList.setAdapter(adapter);
        navList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        navList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        loadSelection(0);
    }

    private void loadSelection(int i){
        navList.setItemChecked(i, true);

        switch (i){
            case 0:
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, homeFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 1:
                AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, aboutUsFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 2:
                HelplineFragment ourWorkFragment = new OurWorkFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, ourWorkFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 3:
                LocateFragment locateFragment = new LocateFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, locateFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 4:
                LocateFragment contactFragment = new ContactUsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, contactFragment)
                        .commit();
                break;


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navList)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(navList);
            }

        }
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        loadSelection(position);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
    }



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentholder">    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationdrawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ccddccdd"
        ></ListView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

 //   ViewFlipper topFlipper;
    ViewFlipper bottomFlipper;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment_text);

        bottomFlipper = (ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomFlipper);
        bottomFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        bottomFlipper.setFlipInterval(2000);
        bottomFlipper.startFlipping();

    return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.drawernav.HomeFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/home_fragment_text"
            android:text="@string/home_fragment_text"
            android:textSize="27sp"
             />

        <ViewFlipper
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/bottomFlipper">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bottomFlipper1"
                android:src="@drawable/flipper1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bottomFlipper2"
                android:src="@drawable/flipper2"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bottomFlipper3"
                android:src="@drawable/flipper3"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bottomFlipper4"
                android:src="@drawable/flipper4"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bottomFlipper5"
                android:src="@drawable/flipper5"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bottomFlipper6"
                android:src="@drawable/flipper6"/>


        </ViewFlipper>


</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Its got something to do with memory allocation is what I gather, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like the image you're setting as the `DrawerLayout`'s background is too big.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: when you try to load heavy Image in terms of Size/Resolution

Comment: change the size of  this background res/drawable/bg.jpg. convert into png format

Comment: I've reduced the resolution and changed to png, will get back with outcome soon!

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.test.drawernav/com.test.drawernav.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:

Its an inflate exception, 
the image you are referring in your res/drawable might have higher pixel resolution. 
its consuming a lot of memory. so try minimizing that src image.

Comment: I've reduced the resolution and changed to png, will get back with outcome soon!